# Reading from files with a particular format

Tags: java

Hello Dear Friends , 
    Well , I'm working on a project , I've defined a function that write data's in a text file , and this function below is what reads data's from files , so there is this little problem , that each data appears to be on a separated JOptionPane message dialog , How can I define a GUI that allows me to format my function in a way that data's appears at the same time ,

```
 int i=0;
 Object[] options = {"OK"};
 try
 {
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 String strLine;

 while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
 {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, strLine +"\n");
 }

 }catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers",       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
 }
```

any help is appreciated,

Comment: store lines somewhere (a list?), format content stored then display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need StringBuffer or StringBuilder.. like this..

```
try
 {
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 String strLine;
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
 {
     sb.append(strLine +"\n");
 }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
 }catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers",       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you need like this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
             builder.append(strLine).append('\n');
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your JOptionPane.showMessageDialog is within the loop.
Use a StringBuilder to append all input and
call JOptionPane.showMessageDialog outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

using IOUtil from Apache common,

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(is);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, filecontent);
is.close();
```

otherwise use StringBuilder and append each line into it.